# Returning array react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to return an array in react-redux, but I get undefined when I try to get them in my react component.

How do I return an array, using the "GET_TODO", "GET_FINISHED", "GET_LATER" cases.

## Reducer, ( GET_ is the one that should return an array )

```
const initialState = {
  today: [1, 2, 3],
  finished: [3, 2, 1, 3],
  later: [2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5]
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {

    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [...state.today, action.payload]
    case 'DELETE_TODO':
      return state.today.filter((item, index) => index !== action.payload)
    case 'GET_TODO':
      return state.today
    case 'ADD_LATER':
      return [...state, action.payload]
    case 'DELETE_LATER':
      return state.filter((item, index) => index !== action.payload)
    case 'GET_LATER':
      return [...state.later]
    case 'ADD_FINISHED':
      return [...state, action.payload]
    case 'DELETE_FINISHED':
      return state.filter((item, index) => index !== action.payload)
    case 'GET_FINISHED':
      return [...state.finished]
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

## React component

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.get();
  }
```

### mapStateToProps & mapDispatchToProps

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    today: state.important.today ? state.important.today : [],
    finished: state.important.finished ? state.important.finished : [],
    later: state.important.later ? state.important.later : [],

  }
}
```

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    add: (value) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TODO', payload: value })
    },
    remove: (index) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_TODO', payload: index })
    },
    get: () => {
      dispatch({type:'GET_TODO'})
    },
    addToFinished: (value) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'ADD_FINISHED', payload: value })
    },
    removeFinished: (index) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_FINISHED', payload: index })
    },
    addToLater: (value) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'ADD_LATER', payload: value })
    },
    removeLater: (index) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_LATER', payload: index })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your actions are being handled by your reducer in a way which will cause you to get undefined. As you have multiple keys on your object, you will need to make sure you are only handling the key in question, for instance:

```js
    case 'DELETE_LATER':
      return state.filter((item, index) => index !== action.payload)
```

Should presumably be:

```
    case 'DELETE_LATER':
      return {
         ...state,
         later: state.later.filter((item, index) => index !== action.payload)
      }
```

And as another example, your ADD_TODO handler will cause problems:

```js
const initialState = {
  today: [1, 2, 3],
  finished: [3, 2, 1, 3],
  later: [2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5]
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {

    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [...state.today, action.payload]
    case 'DELETE_TODO':
      return state.today.filter((item, index) => index !== action.payload)
    case 'GET_TODO':
      return state.today
    case 'ADD_LATER':
      return [...state, action.payload]
    case 'DELETE_LATER':
      return state.filter((item, index) => index !== action.payload)
    case 'GET_LATER':
      return [...state.later]
    case 'ADD_FINISHED':
      return [...state, action.payload]
    case 'DELETE_FINISHED':
      return state.filter((item, index) => index !== action.payload)
    case 'GET_FINISHED':
      return [...state.finished]
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const newState = reducer(initialState, { type: 'ADD_TODO', payload: 3})

console.dir(newState)
```

Notice that you've now lost the other keys from your state.

---

As an additional comment, when you're returning an array, the code:

```js
return [...array]
```

Is equivalent to:

```js
return array
```

Comment: It still returns an error though:  TypeError: state.today is not iterable

Comment: @Johan In that case I imagine that your reducer does not always return state in the form which it took in `initialState`, which is why parts of it have problems. if `state.today` is not iterable, then it isn't an array, which means your state has a different form at that point